# error on article and punctuation

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-construction

Here is my small paragraph.

> The accepted object is further verified by fitting a circle for a
>   selected slice. If **the** circle fitting error is lower than **the**
>   defined threshold`,` it is accepted as a circular object.

Can i use the article '***the***' with some nouns even though we are using them for the first time within a sentence?

Comment: This is two questions. I've edited the second question out. Please feel free to re-ask it as a separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the definite article in both the cases you are talking of something very specific:  *the circle fitting error* and *the defined threshold*. You are not talking of a generic error or a generic threshold.

The comma you used in that sentence is fine, and it is normally used in those cases.

> If you are happy, clap your hands.

Comment: thank for the quick answer. so i think my sentence is error free. is that so?